# Count number of Triggers in a given Span of Time

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I've been working for a while with some cheap PIR modules and a raspberry pi 3. My aim is to use 4 of these guys to understand if a room is empty, and turn off some lights in case.

Now, this lovely sensors aren't really precise. They false trigger from time to time, and they don't trigger right after their status has changed, and this makes things much harder.

I thought I could solve the problem measuring a sort of *"density of triggers"*, meaning how many triggers occurred during the last 60 seconds or something.

My question is how could I implement effectively this solution? I thought to build a sort of container and fill it with elements with a timer or something, but I'm not really sure this would do the trick.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

How are you powering PIR sensors? They should be powered with 5V. I had similar problem with false triggers when I was powered PIR sensor with only 3.3V.

Comment: Might be a clue of what's going on, but I'm powering them at 5V. I also changed the RPi supply with a "better" one (I had some low power alerts from time to time).